# Rails :: in nested model form, update belongs_to "parent" attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested, simple-form, belongs-to

I am building a Rails application and I am in front of an issue with form I can't fix.
I have an `order` model which belongs_to `customer` so when I build the form I do `@order = @customer.orders.build`

This works well to save orders attributes but I also want to update customer attributes as well which never work.

How can I save order and update "parent" customer attributes in the same process ?

Thanks for your help !

Edit:

**Customer model:**

```
class Customer < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :orders
end
```

**Order model:**

```
class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :customer
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :customer
end
```

**My project**:

- Ruby On Rails 4.2.6 / Ruby 2.2.2
- Devise 3.5.9
- Simple form 3.1.0

Comment: update customer attributes means what? You want to send some attributes that should be saved to the `customer` object OR you want to set some attributes depending on the `order`?

Comment: Customer has a profile with some fields (name, address, city, ...). In the order form, there is a section where the customer can update some of his informations. So when customer submit the form it should create an order AND update customer profile informations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should update your customer in your create method. How about:

```
    def create
        @order = current_customer.orders.build order_params
        if @order.save
          @order.customer.update_attributes(order_params[:customer_attributes])
          ...
        else
          ...
        end
      end
```

Answer (score 0):

In your update action, you can do something like this:

```
def update
  @customer = Customer.find(params[:id])
  if @customer.update_attributes(customer_params.merge({ order_attributes: order_params}))
     render @customer
  end 
end
```

Where `customer_params` and `order_params` are methods that use strong params to whitelist parameters sent by the form.

Obviously, I haven't tested the code, but ti should give you some direction.

Hope that helps!